# Play Ebean List null

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have an issue using Ebean to save a list of object.

I have a three class. the last one included two children class.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="A")
public class A extends Model {

    @Id
    public String idA;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "currentA")
    private List<B> listOfB;   
}
```

The second class B :

```
@Entity
public class B  extends Model  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long idB;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idA")
    private A currentA;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "currentB")
    public ArrayList<C> lstOfC;

    public B(List<C> lstC) {
        this.lstOfC=lstC;
    }
}
```

And the last one :

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("X")

public class C extends Model {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "idB")
    private B currentB;

    private setcurrentB(int currentB) {
        this.currentB=currentB;
    }      
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I need to create a list of C object (lstOfC) but I do not know the value of currentB when I put the element in the list.
I need to set (with a setter) this value later then save it to the database.

But when I try that, the list of C object is null from the list of B in A.

```
ArrayList<C> lstC=new ArrayList<C>();

c1=new C();
c2=new C();
B=new B(lstC);

for (C c: lstC) {
    c.setcurrentB(1);
    Ebean.save(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You example doesn't quite make sense where setcurrentB(1) ... takes 1 but expects an instance of B - I presume that is a reference bean.

It seems like you want to temporarily turn off cascade persist and you can do that on the Transaction.

```
Transaction tranaction = Ebean.beginTransaction();
try {
  // turn off persist cascade for this transaction
  transaction.setPersistCascade(false);

  for (C c: listC) {

  }

  Ebean.commitTransaction();

} finally {
  Ebean.endTransaction();
}
```